# Swift optionals nil check

Tags: ios, swift

So I fail to figure a 1 liner for following syntax in Swift and it is driving me nuts:

```
if lastProfile == nil || lastProfile.id == profile.id {
        useProfile(profile)
        lastProfile = profile
}
```

Now see I could chain it but I'd still end up with 2-3 ifs. I could pack it out but then I again end up with 2-3 ifs... Is it possible to do this in just 1 swoop?

Edit:

My colleague found an alternative (although we agree ugly):

```
if !(latestProfile != nil && latestProfile!.voiceId != profile.voiceId) {

}
```

Is there a better approach than above?

Comment: Your last profile is already nullable, why not just latestProfile?voiceId = profile.voiceId?

Comment: @Brduca I want to enter block if it is nul or if there is a match in voice id.

Comment: I must be dense.  What is wrong with your first example and how is the second one any better?

Comment: Clever one-liners make the code more difficult to read/understand. Down the road, you or someone else will have to look at this and grasp the intent of this code.

Comment: i already posted an answer but the more i read the question the more i do not really understand what the question actually is... :)

Comment: An alternative is to declare `lastProfile` as non-optional and set the `id` to a default value which never occurs (-1 or `Int.max`). Then you get rid of the `nil` check.

Comment: It is safe to do `if lastProfile == nil || lastProfile!.id == profile.id` because short circuiting will prevent the forced unwrap if `lastProfile` is `nil`.

Comment: "Figuring out a one liner" seems like the wrong reason to modify something. Why not wrap the functionality to a function instead `func shouldSetProfile(profile) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is just a `?` away:

```
if lastProfile == nil || lastProfile?.id == profile.id {
    print("true")
    lastProfile = profile
}
```

This prints "true" when lastProfile is nil or when lastProfile and profile have the same id. Otherwise it prints nothing.

Comment: G damn it. Had gotten into my head that I couldn't use == nil because of an error I had gotten months ago so I didn't even look further down the line...

Answer (score 0):

If `lastProfile` is declared as `let lastProfile: Profile? = ...`, and for example id is declared as optional also you can use it as:

```
if let lastProfileId = lastProfile?.id { 
    // lastProfile is not nil and id is not nil
}
else {
    // lastProfile is nil or lastProfile.id is nil
}
```

It is called Optional Chaining and you can read about it on swift [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html).

Answer (score -1):

```
if let recentProfile = latestProfile where recentProfile.voieId != profile.voiceId {
    useProfile(profile)
    lastProfile = profile
}
```

Comment: Would I enter block if it were nil? If NO... then no this aint better.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question, answer above is good by jboi

Comment: Thats is okay. Thanks for trying to help this imbecile :) (I didn't down vote btw.)

Comment: Neither did I. Your answer made me think what the 'where' in Swift is good for. There're still some miracles in this language.